# there exist integer $x,y$ such this $x^5y+3,y^5x+3$ are third power?

Tags: number-theory

there exist integer $x,y$ such this 
$x^5y+3,y^5x+3$ are third power?

By the Now,I can't find one example such this condition,so I guess maybe there not exsit $x,y$?

$$xy(x^4-y^4)=xy(x+y)(x^2+y^2)(x-y)=m^3-n^3,m,n\in Z$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there are no such integers. Suppose $x,y$ are solutions. Then they are not divisible by $3$. Because cubic residues modulo $9$ are $0,1,8$ we obtain that
$xy^5$ and $x^5y$ are either $5\bmod 9$ or $7\bmod 9$. However, $x^5 \equiv x^{-1} \pmod{9}$ and we obtain linear conditions yielding $3\mid x$, or $3\mid y$, hence a contradiction.

Actually, this was an  2013 USAJMO [Problem](http://www.artofproblemsolving.com/community/c3420_usajmo), and detailed solutions are available online.

Comment: Nice ,why $xy^5$and $x^5y$ are either $5\pmod 9,$or $7\pmod 9$?

Comment: $x^5y+3$ is $1,8$ modulo $9$, so $x^5y$ is $1-3,8-3$ modulo $9$, i.e., $7$ or $5$.

Comment: Thank you very much,I have understand